# Can I add pipes to an existing observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I want an init function to control my code initialization process for readability - a roadmap of sorts.

```
myObservable$;

init() {
  this.watchChanges()
  this.updateOptionsOnChange()
  this.patchValuesOnOptionUpdate();
}

watchChanges () {
  myObservable$ = this.something.pipe(
    mergeMap(change => hitApi)
  )
}

updateOptionsOnChange() {
  //here I want to "Add" a pipe to the existing pipes above
  myObservable$.pipe(
    tap(add values to an object/array)
  )
}

this.patchValuesOnChanges() {
  myObservable$.subscribe(
    set values based on above tap ^
  )
};
```

Can I do this without making another observable in `updateOptionsOnChange`. Is this just an anti-pattern to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `myObservable$ = myObservable$.pipe(tap(add values to an object/array))`. There is not a way to change the existing Observable's pipeline "in-place" like you are describing.

It would probably be more "reactive" to have two different Observables that you then combine together in `patchValuesOnChanges`, where one of the Observables is sourced from `updateOptionsOnChange`.

Comment: You should not change instances of observables on properties, you should create have an observable that switchMap to different paths

Comment: Do not use this technique, switchMap is the answer you are looking for. This way you are continually creating and destroying observables.

Comment: @AdrianBrand I mention that approach in my second paragraph. The first paragraph more closely answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a switchMap on a BehaviorSubject to switch witch observable you want to use.

```js
const { BehaviorSubject, interval } = rxjs;
const { switchMap, map } = rxjs.operators;

let useApi$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

let switchButton = document.getElementById('switch');

switchButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (useApi$.value) {
    switchButton.innerText = 'Local';
    useApi$.next(false);
  } else {
    switchButton.innerText = 'API';
    useApi$.next(true);
  }
});

let local$ = interval(1000).pipe(map(_ => 'local'));
let api$ = interval(1000).pipe(map(_ => 'api'));

let myObservable$ = useApi$.pipe(
  switchMap(useApi => useApi ? api$ : local$)
);

myObservable$.subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<button id="switch">Local</button>
```